# How does the MVC 4 Login/SimpleMembership work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking to upgrade a project I have from ASP.NET Web Forms to MVC 4.

In the process of the upgrade I am trying to re-evaluate the way we handle authentication and login.

Currently, when a user attempts to log in, I (the front-end), make a call to the database to validate and then that comes back as yay or nay with an associated 'token'. I then have to pass that token to the next page on our site where it gets placed into a javascript object. That token is then passed with every ajax call and is updated after each with a new token. I personally manage that token within the client browser.

Now, in MVC 4 the default Internet Application comes with the needed logic to employ some form of local registration and login. But I don't understand how it works.

**After a user 'registers' where does that get stored?**

**When a user is logged in and then changes pages, how does that user stay logged in?How does his credentials get passed?**

It seems to me that the current way that we handle our login is grossly outdated and flawed. But at this time I do not understand how I could setup MVC to look at our current (external, its not within this project) database to authenticate users.

I have a book on MVC 4 but it doesn't seem to go into detail on how this works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar question, you can see my post **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000824/mvc-4-connectionstring-to-sql-server-2012)**, but the solution I found and went with was from **[this article](http://www.dwdmbi.com/2012/09/visual-studio-2012-uses.html)**. It's very detailed with how the new SimpleMembership system works.

The biggest change is that you no longer need any of the aspnet_regsql stuff anymore. Once you register, the database schema gets created along with a row for the user. No SP's or Views required!

Answer (score 7):

> After a user 'registers' where does that get stored

If you used VS2012, ASP.NET MVC 4, it will store the user in [`LocalDB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx). That's the default out-of-the-box implementation that uses the new [`Simple Membership Provider`](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx).

> When a user is logged in and then changes pages, how does that user
>   stay logged in?How does his credentials get passed?

The currently authenticated user is stored in a encrypted [`Forms Authentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) cookie. Look at the `LogOn` POST action which emits this cookie.